# can we show some part of image in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to make one image slider  in which user slide it images .I am able to make slider but there is issue in that .it show `one` image at one time . In other words it show `one` image in `ul`.
but I want

- when app run it show first image along the it show some part of image two .see below image

[image]

- when user click on `next` .it show second image along that it also show some part of third and first image .as example

[image]

can we make this type of slider in jquery .

I tried like this

https://jsfiddle.net/uvsb6asa/10/

```
$(function(){
    $('#next').click(function(){
        addToMarginLeft($('.outer ul'), -210);
    });
    $('#pre').click(function(){
        addToMarginLeft($('.outer ul'), 210);
    });

  function addToMarginLeft(elem, pixels) {
    var ml = parseFloat(elem.css('margin-left'));
    elem.animate({
    'margin-left': (ml + pixels) + 'px'
    },1000)

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in CSS the `width` in `.outer` and `margin-left` in `.outer ul`

```
.outer {
width:400px;
overflow:hidden
}
.outer ul {
    width: 610px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px
    margin-left:100px;  
}
```

```js
$(function(){
 $('#next').click(function(){
  addToMarginLeft($('.outer ul'), -210);
 });
 $('#pre').click(function(){
  addToMarginLeft($('.outer ul'), 210);
 });
  
  function addToMarginLeft(elem, pixels) {
   var ml = parseFloat(elem.css('margin-left'));
    elem.animate({
    'margin-left': (ml + pixels) + 'px'
    },1000)

  }
});
```

```css
.outer {
width:300px;
overflow:hidden
}
.outer ul {
    width: 610px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px
    margin-left:100px;

    
    
}

.outer li {
    display: inline-block;

   
}
.outer li img {
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <ul>
        <li><img alt=""  src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
        <li><img alt=""  src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7lw5rwUWCsmOFSTUuFF84niMBZg6J9KeWhws1Ysib3VdVTM8-RA"></li>
        <li><img alt=""   src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQITZTZxY9nTV6pm2M0lbyXVt03SyyD9I1Th1aJ8UfeFbF2FE0oXLoUKUDd"></li>
    
    </ul>
     <button id='pre'>
    previous
    </button>
    <button id='next'>
    next
    </button>
   
</div>
```

Comment: it is not working https://jsbin.com/fedacukape/edit?html,css,js,output.when I added multiple images

Comment: pls remove this answer it is not working https://jsbin.com/gerukezina/edit?html,js,output

Comment: its working fine, in your jsbin you changed .outer width to 500px and .outer ul width to 1820px, try changing margin-left to 40px; also this   addToMarginLeft($('.outer ul'), -250);
should be   addToMarginLeft($('.outer ul'), -300);